# Automatic link to different language version of a document (sphinx)

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm creating a multi-page document in two different languages (English and French) with possibly other languages to be added.  The url of a given document will take the form of   prefix/en/name.html  or prefix/fr/name.html  i.e. only the "en" or "fr" part will be different.  Is is possible to include some code in the main template (layout.html  ... or elsewhere?) that would take the url of the current (English) document, replace "/en/" by "/fr/" and insert it as a link to the "French" version?  Something like

```
automatically retrieve:
    prefix/en/this_document.html  
transform into:  
<a href="prefix/fr/this_document.html">French</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I essentially found the answer I needed in this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sphinx-users/Xmbs5AbnVKY

Basically, what I do is insert the following:

```
<a href="{{pathto("../en/"+pagename)}}">{{"English version"}}</a>
```

where needed.